# How to search two or more parameter in java spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have got two cars in my database(MySQL). The first is red(String color) Ferrari(String brand) and second is red(String color) Lamborghini(String brand). When I'm looking only after brand for example: "ferrari" the result is all cars which brand is "ferrari". Ok that's good result. But problem is when in the field I enter two parameters or more, for example: brand=ferrari and color=red. Enter. And the result is red Ferrari and red Lamborghini but it should be only red Ferrari because I typed "Ferrari" and "Red". How to return correct result? This is my method from CarRepository.

```
List<Car> cars = carRepository.findByBrandOrModel(List<String> brands, List<String> models);
```

I don't know how to correct this method. Only I know the "OR" is incorrect. Can anyone help me? [This is my controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efQ7D.png)

[entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0nad.png)

Comment: it should probably look like: select * from car where brand = ?1 and color = ?2, If you could pass the car entity I can probably write the method.

Comment: @NenadVichentikj post edited, please look for "entity"

Comment: I have a question, why are you sending Lists as parameters ?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on Stack Overflow instead of Images, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and if not already done, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: That's what I did at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the search like this. in the pics you posted, we can't see the method findByBrandOrModel

```
List<Car> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Car car: cars) {
        if (car.getColor().equals("red") && car.getBrand().equals("Ferrari") {
            result.add(car);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

CarRepository

```
List<Car> findByBrandAndModel(String brands, String models);
```

After that the controller, should have,

```
List<Car> cars = carRepository.findByBrandAndModel("red", "ferrari");
```

/-----------------------------------
Or a better Implementation

CarRepository

```
Optional<List<Car>> findByBrandAndModel(String brands, String models);
```

After that the controller, should have:

```
Optional<List<Car>> carsOptional = carRepository.findByBrandAndModel("red", "ferrari");
carOptional.ifPresent(e -> do stuff with the cars here);
```

This should do the trick...

Comment: There's no reason to use `Optional` on a collection return.

Comment: That`s true, it will return Collection.emptyList() by default.